# Save emails from IMAP account via Kmail

Tags: kubuntu, email, kmail

I am having an email account that I am managing with Kmail via IMAP. I would like to delete the email account, but keep the emails. How can I save the emails on my harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description on how to archive: https://userbase.kde.org/Kmail/Backup_Options

Right click on the folder and press "archive folder".